# Did Aristarchus take the radius of the Earth into account in calculating the distance to the Moon?

Tags: astronomy, history, moon, orbital-motion

My [text](http://books.google.com/books?id=ntZwxttZF-sC&lpg=PA28&ots=LU-xi3_Vw5&dq=lunar%20dichotomy%20method&pg=PA27#v=onepage&q=lunar%20dichotomy%20method&f=false) says that Aristarchus (310 BC – ~230 BC) measured the "angle subtended by the Earth-Moon distance at the Sun" ($\theta$ in the figure below) to establish the relative Earth-Moon and Earth-Sun distances.

[image]

I understand that he must, in fact have used the [Moon-Earth-Sun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristarchus_On_the_Sizes_and_Distances#Half_Moon) angle, and then subtracted that from 90° to arrive at $\theta$; but how did he establish the Moon-Earth-Sun angle? The reference points for all three objects is their centers, yet what Aristarchus must have in fact measured was the angle between the Moon and the Sun at the *surface* of the Earth.

Did Aristarchus take this discrepancy into account in his calculations? If so, how?

Comment: A diagram would be appreciated, even if Aristarchus  just ignored the issue and it shows that demonstrates that the discrepancy simply didn't matter much; and especially if he used some clever geometric trick that is glossed over in the standard explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He ignored the radius of the Earth as negligible. His estimates for the angle were from the shape of the shadow the sun casts on the moon, and the difference between this and a straight line when the moon is halfway between full and new is too small to percieve precisely. He fooled himself into thinking he measured a different angle, so his estimate was really only giving a lower bound on the distance to the sun. As a lower bound, it was enough to establish that the sun is larger than the Earth, and this was important, in that it lent strong support to heliocentric models. But it was not an accurate method.

Comment: Yes, it seems more like he described a method, rather than actually "measuring" anything (in the modern sense). Is it fair to say that this was a characteristic (perhaps "weakness") of the ancient Greek style: the focus on reasoning and forms and constructing arguments, with "measurements" often guessed at or very roughly estimated?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius - I would say Aristarchos is one of the few Greeks who actually did science = measuring things. Rather than just reasoning from arbitrary ideas of perfect shapes

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: In this case, he fooled himself into thinking he measured a different angle, so his estimate is really a lower bound on the distance to the sun. As a lower bound, it was enough to establish that the sun is larger than the Earth, and this was important. I don't think he took his estimate too seriously, he knew he needed a better method, but you need _something_ to start, and he did the best he could. I agree with Martin Beckett--- don't assume that the Ancient Greek scientists (Aristarchus/Archimedes/Appolonius) were as stupid as Aristotle.

Comment: Understood, so perhaps "meaningless" is a bit harsh.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: You're right, fixed.

Comment: @RonMaimon: Don't call Aristotle stupid unless you think you coudl develop formal logic from nothing, in addition to a huge, huge proliferation of work that was important in a bunch of different diciplines.  The Politics was the first systematic study of political systems, for instance.  the pre-moderns blindly citing Aristotle was far more of a problem than Aristotle himself.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: He did not develop formal logic, or else I wouldn't call him stupid. I have skimmed what he called "logic", and it is syllogisms only, without the essential deductive machinery that was produced by mathematicians. This deductive machinery is encapsulated in the generalization rule--- from deducing a property P on a free variable x with no assumptions, you deduce "forall x" P(x). This part is the essence of logic, what Aristotle wrote about is vapid nonsense.

Comment: @RonMaimon: patent nonsense.  There are quantifiers in Aristotelian logic.  There was nothing significant done in logic between the end of antiquity and Cantor.  If you want to say that everything worthwhile in logic was done by Cantor, Frege, Godel, Whitehead, and Russell, have at it, but that is a radical minority position.

Comment: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/#aris

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: There was nothing significant in logic until Frege, Hilbert, Godel, Whitehead and Russell. Aristotle did not give a scheme of deduction, all he had were syllogisms. I know for sure, I looked at his stuff. The main insight is probably due to Hilbert, (just a guess) when he developed his informal deduction algorithm, but the reason it wasn't developed earlier is because the same gang of mental-defectives who are now busy writing the SEP claimed Aristotle solved the problem, when, like everything else, he only pretend-solved it and held back the founding of the field by centuries.

Comment: ... I would like to debunk this further, because it really is this guy's last claim to fame. The issue with sylllogisms is that your deduction is not computationally complex, you only deduce finitely many things from finitely many premises, nothing of higher complexity. The essence of _real_ logic is to deduce higher complexity sentences from simple axioms. This absolutely requires generative rules that include deductions which are not syllogisms, and these were introduced in the early 20th century. Logic without these is not logic, but philosopher's logic, just a vapid rhetorical format.

Comment: ... This is not only a radical minority position, I think it is the position of a minority of _one person_, namely, me! This doesn't make me doubt it, it makes me dismiss the people who have considered this and disagree with me as incompetent. I won't budge on this, it is obvious from reading Aristototle.

Comment: @RonMaimon: funny, that's exactly what Euclid did, and Euclid was certainly exposed to Aristotelian thought in Hellensitic Egypt.  And all of the Elements follow from the five axioms and syllogistic reasoning.  Aristotelain logic is all there is until you start dealing with infinites or conditionals or modal logic.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: No it doesn't! You cannot go backwards like this, it is ridiculous, Euclid and Aristotle are near contemporaries, and Aristotle is writing vapid crap, while Euclid is doing _real deduction_ not "just" using syllogism, but also introducing _new points_, making assumptions on these new points, and then using syllogism for some deductions, and when there are conclusions, he writes down "assumption implies conclusion". The syllogisms are the _least important part of the procedure_, they are just the part that Aristotle noticed is most rhetorically persuasive to a non-mathematician.

Comment: @RonMaimon: near contemporaries = Euclid is of the next generation, living under the guardinaship of Aristotle's student.  You admit that every scholar on this subject is on my side.  I understand that you have a vendetta against Aristotle, all I ask is that you not weridly call him a wholly worthless moron.